# Does level matter when metamorphing a familiar?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

Does the level of a familiar have any impact on its metamorphosis? Let's say I have two mites. If one of them is max level and the other one is the minimum level required to morph, and I morph them both to their next form, will the resultant two familiars be any different?

Excluding learned skills, some of which I realize are learned beyond the minimum morph level for certain familiars. I'm asking primarily about attribute points.

Comment: Answered my own question...this image appears to show that yes, level pre-morph matters for determining stats: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OUB2j.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The level at which you morph a familiar does affect its starting stats in its next form.

The game will tell you:

1. When the familiar is able to be morphed to the next form
2. When the familiar is at its maximum level for its current form

If you're planning on using a familiar for post-game play you should definitely wait until he is at the maximum level for each form before morphing him.

In addition to the stats being higher, you may miss out learning some abilities if you always morph familiars as soon as they are able.