# What impacts the attributes of a familiar when it is metamorphed?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I know that [level impacts the attributes of a  familiar when it metamorphs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103196/does-level-matter-when-metamorphing-a-familiar), but does anything else have an impact? I'm particularity curious if the treats I give a familiar have any impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treats do not have an impact on stats gained after metamorphosis. The stat bonus from treats is a static bonus (up to a max of 50 stat points) and this carries over between metamorphosis.

Levelling a familiar to max level for it's current form before you metamorphose will guarantee the best possible stat growth for that given familiar.